# How to efficiently display raw rgb int array in javafx?

Tags: java, javafx

I have an int array where each value stores a bitpacked rgb value (8 bits per channel) and alpha is always 255(opaque) and i want to display that in javafx.

My current approach is using a canvas like this:

```java
GraphicsContext graphics = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
PixelWriter pw = graphics.getPixelWriter();
pw.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(), pixels, 0, width);
```

However before that i actually have to set the alpha component of each pixel by iterating each pixel and OR'ing it with a mask that turns the pixel from rgb to argb like this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
    pixels[i] = 0xFF000000 | pixels[i];
}
```

Is there a more efficient to do this (as the pixels array is updated many times every second)?

I was hoping there's a IntRgbInstance but unfortunately there isn't (only ByteRgbInstance)

Other approaches i've tested:

Approach 1: Creating a IntBuffer that is filled up like this:

```java
IntBuffer buffer = IntBuffer.allocate(pixels.length * 4);
for (int pixel : pixels) {
    buffer.put(0xFF000000 | pixel);
}
```

And then generating a PixelBuffer that uses this buffer, the pixel buffer is then used as an input to this WritableImage constructor: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.scene.image.PixelBuffer)
and then i display that WritableImage using a ImageView

This however still didn't speed up anything(rather made it a bit slower) and im guessing that because i have to construct a new WritableImage instance each time the pixels int array is updated.

Approach 2 (that didn't work for some reason, i.e. it displayed nothing in the screen): Creating a buffer the same way as above and using that in one of the setPixels() methods that takes in a buffer:

```java
IntBuffer buffer = IntBuffer.allocate(pixels.length * 4);
for (int pixel : pixels) {
    buffer.put(0xFF000000 | pixel);
}
pw.setPixels(0, 0, width, height, PixelFormat.getIntArgbInstance(), buffer, width);
```

After a bit of more research i found out that i don't need to create a new WritableImage instance each time the pixels array is updated but i can just use the updateBuffer method here: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/PixelBuffer.html#updateBuffer(javafx.util.Callback)

So the code currently looks like this:

```java
pb.updateBuffer(callback -> {
    buffer.clear();
    for (int pixel : pixels) {
        buffer.put(0xFF000000 | pixel);
    }
    return null;
});
```

Where pb, buffer is only created once like this:

```java
IntBuffer buffer = IntBuffer.allocate(pixels.length * 4);
PixelBuffer<IntBuffer> pb = new PixelBuffer<>(width, height, buffer, PixelFormat.getIntArgbPreInstance());
view.setImage(new WritableImage(pb));
```

and this did indeed result in a nice speedup (close to 2x compared to my initial approach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.scene.image.PixelBuffer) is what you are looking for. You could create a PixelBuffer from an IntBuffer of your data.

Comment: Thank you, together with using PixelBuffer#updateBuffer() i did indeed get a rather nice speedup (about 2x compared to my initial approach) i will wait a few days for other answers just in case (altho i think this is the best approach there is) and after that i'll accept this answer

Comment: Yes, using updateBuffer() is the essential part of the PixelBuffer. It would not make much sense without it. I used it for real-time rendering of 4K videos from VLC in JavaFX. You can even use double-buffering that way if you want to.